# функция onclick в javascript не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, html5

функция onclick в javascript не срабатывает в консоле ошибок нет но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

```js
function func1() {
    
    var radio1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    var radio2 = document.getElementById("radio2");
    var radio3 = document.getElementById("radio3");
    var radio4 = document.getElementById("radio4");
    var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

    if (radio1.checked == true) {

        alert("radio1 is checked");
    }
    else if (radio2.checked == true){
        alert("radio2 is checked");
    }
    else if (radio3.checked == true){
        alert("radio3 is checked");
    }
    else if (radio4.checked == true){
        alert("radio4 is checked");
    }
    else{
        alert("please select answer");
    }
        
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Round One</p>
    <h1>11111</h1>

    
    <div class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
    <label for="radio1">222</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">
        <label for="radio2">3333</label>
        </div>
    
        
    <div class="radio-group">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3">
            <label for="radio3">4444</label>
            </div>

    <div class="radio-group">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4">
            <label for="radio4">555</label>
            </div>
    
        
        <a href="#" class="myButton" id="btn2" onclick="func1">
            
        </a>
            
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
onclick="func1"
```

на

```
onclick="func1()"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! все работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй перенести подключение скрипта в конец, перед закрывающим тегом body.

```
<body>

<script src="script.js">
</body>
```

Также, при использовании инлайн обработчиков, нужно писать так:

```
    <a href="#" class="myButton" id="btn2" onclick="func1()">
        button
    </a>
```

Comment: Пытался,все равно не срабатывает